Prove that $ \sum _{j=0}^n \frac{(-1)^j (1-j)^n}{j! (n-j)!} = 1 $
I have shown via geometric methods that the below result is actual, but I cannot prove it via algebraic means. I have tried a simple proving approach through induction but cannot get it right. I'm hoping someone can assist.
Prove that this result holds
$$
\sum _{j=0}^n \frac{(-1)^j (1-j)^n}{j! (n-j)!} = 1
$$

This question is similar to: Can this summation be proved to equal 1 for any upper bound 0 or greater?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. (To relate them explicitly, take $i=n-j$ and do some minor algebra.)
